# Check on Create Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this:

```
create table airport
(idairport varchar(1),
name varchar(1),
city varchar(1),
primary key(idairport));
```

Is it possible to check that one city doesn't have more than 3 airports?

Edited:

The exercise is:

[image]

Translate to the relational model a conceptual schema. We want to know, for each airport, the aircrafts that have been there and the possible destinations. If the model is not normalized, normalize it avoiding the existence of null values.

Constraints:

- There is not any flight leaving an airport and landing in the same
  airport.
- A city has, at most, three airports.

The solution must be a set of "CREATE TABLE" sentences. Express as many integrity constraints as you can. Specify all "NOT NULL" due to the relational translation and only these. Furthermore, you shouldn't forget to define the necessary foreign and alternative keys (UNIQUE+NOT NULL).

After translation(If I'm not wrong):

```
create table aircraft
(idaircraft varchar(1),
seating varchar(1),
primary key(idaircraft));

create table destination
(idairportorigin varchar(1) references airport(idairport),
idairportdestination varchar(1) references airport(idairport),
idaircraft varchar(1),
check(idairportorigin <> idairportdestination),
primary key(idairportorigin, idairportdestination, idaircraft),
foreign key (idaircraft) references aircraft(idaircraft));
```

Comment: You can use Insert/Update Triggers to add checks on data being inserted or updated

Comment: On 'create table' is possible?

Comment: all the varchar(1) is just because this is an example, right?

Comment: Not on create table, i don't think any rdbms has option to create tables with conditions on data. You should first create table and then add triggers

Comment: Considering the difference between the answers and the comments, I think that you have to clarify; Do you simply want to count the airports for cities, or do you want the database to prevent anyone from connecting more than three airports to a city?

Comment: @MikeC. Yes, no matter on types.

Comment: @GUffa I need to prevent that a city have more than 3 airports without using triggers, I think that is impossible without using triggers, for that reason I asked the question.

Comment: The condition regarding the maximum number of airports per city does not happen at the create table level.  It happens when you write data with either insert or update queries.

Comment: I believe OP is looking for **constraint-type** condition that is set at creation (or alter) but actually functions for inserts and updates.

Comment: Triggers will not enforce the constraint safely because read consistency prevents each session from seeing other uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will tell you.

```
 select city, count(city) citycount
 from airport
 group by city
 having count(city) >=3
```

Comment: When you create a table it doesn't have any records to check.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk - When you create a table and specify (let say) `NOT NULL` there are still no records to check but the limitation can be instituted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to check that one city doesn't have more than 3 airports?"

Not with a normalised data model, using only create table statements.

Even using triggers alone is not sufficient due to read consistency preventing transactions from seeing other uncommited transactions.

The only safe way of doing this is to use an on-commit materialised view that stores the count, with a constraint placed on the MV table's count column to prevent it from exceeding 3.

Comment: Nah, you can put a lock inside the trigger.Read the (good) book: "applied mathematics for database professional"

Comment: You have to lock the whole friggin table to make the trigger work. That will kill concurrency. On the upside I doubt any real application would have many changes to the airport to city mapping.

Comment: Welllllll, you could use DBMS_Lock to serialise changes only on the city, but that's still outside of the limitations of the question. Also it can't be done within the trigger -- the serialisation has to be controlled in the transaction so other sessions can't read the table with the intent to make changes.

Answer (score -2):

If you write trigger in your db then the following sql will give you count of airport-

`select count(idairport) from airport where city = 'entered city'`,

and then you can discard addition of any airport from the city in your pre-insert or pre-update trigger.

and also if you use some programming api like jdbc etc -

then also by above sql you will have count of airport before entering/updating any data and then you can discard the addition/updation from this point of coding.

Comment: -1 Will not stop two sessions from adding #3 and #4 at the same time. Each session would see two existing and then add there update.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance is correct -- read consistency prevents triggers alone from being a safe method of enforcing the constraint.